# How to get counter of each word in windowed stream on Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to get the count of words with windowed function for each word:

If I use this code :

```
object WindowWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

    val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .sum(1)

    counts.print

    env.execute("Window Stream WordCount")
  }
}
```

I get output after 5 seconde (windowed time) like this:

input:

```
first input : hello
seconde input : hello
third input : word
fifth input : hello
sixth input : word
```

output

```
first output : hello : 3 | word : 2
```

but I want to have the output with count for every word.

like that :
input:

```
first input: hello
seconde input:hello
third input:word
fifth input:hello
sixth input:word
```

out put:

```
first output: hello : 1
seconde output:hello : 2
third output:word : 1
fifth output:hello : 3
sixth output:word : 2
```

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the example program for Kafka Streaming API be exactly what you are looking for?
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/datastream_api.html#example-program

```
object WindowWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

    val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .keyBy(0)
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .sum(1)

    counts.print

    env.execute("Window Stream WordCount")
  }
}
```

Comment: The example print all 5 Second And I want to print for each event.

Comment: To clarify a bit, are you asking for processing time windows (as opposed to event-time windows), and are the windows aligned (i.e. do you want the counters for all the keys to be cleared to zero at the same time, every five seconds)?

Comment: Yes, I asking for  processing time windows , I don't want  to clean the data to zero. I just want to count the number of the same words from the last 5 seconde for each word.